# Insert Custom HTML After Shortcode

Tags: filters, shortcode, the-content, regex, post-content

The scenario is that I need to add an HTML banner under a slideshow which is a shortcode in the homepage content. I personally hate adding a bunch of `div` tags to the TinyMCE editor so I'm trying to filter `the_content` and add my HTML after the specific shortcode. Below is a solution but I wasn't sure if there was a better way to go about this.

What's the best way to add content after specific shortcodes?

Comment: What kind of shortcode is this, homemade or from a 3rd party plugin/theme ?

Comment: @birgire plugin - specifically in this case `rev_slider`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder if you could override the `[rev_slider]` with this kind of wrapper:

```php
add_shortcode( 'rev_slider', function( $atts = array(), $content = '' )
{
    $html = '';

    // Your custom banner HTML
    $banner = '<div id="bannerHTML"><!-- banner HTML goes here --></div>';

    // Append your banner HTML to the revslider's output
    if( function_exists( 'rev_slider_shortcode' ) )
        $html = rev_slider_shortcode( $atts, $content ) . $banner;

    return $html;

} );
```

Where we assume that the original shortcode's callback is `rev_slider_shortcode()`. We have to run the after the original one.

### Update

As suggested by @Sumit we could try to get the shortcode's callback from the `$shortcode_tags` array.

Here's an example:

```php
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', function() use ( &$shortcode_tags )
{
    // Shortcode to override. Edit to your needs
    $shortcode = 'rev_slider';

    // Nothing to do if it's not registered as shortcode
    if( ! shortcode_exists( $shortcode ) )
        return; 

    // Get the shortcode's callback
    $callback = $shortcode_tags[$shortcode];

    // Override the shortcode
    add_shortcode( $shortcode, function( $atts = array(), $content = '' ) use ( $callback )
    {
        // Your custom banner HTML
        $banner = '<div id="bannerHTML">123<!-- banner HTML goes here --></div>';

        // Append your banner HTML to the revslider's output
        return 
            is_callable( $callback ) 
            ? call_user_func( $callback, $atts, $content, $callback ) . $banner 
            : '';
    } );

}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

Here we hook late into the `after_setup_theme` action and use `call_user_func()` to run the previous shortcode's callback, similar how it's done in `do_shortcode_tag()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution I've come up with after refining it a bit. The below *should* only run if the shortcode exists in the content. It loops through all the shortcodes to find the specific one we need, replaces it with the shortcode plus the new HTML:

```php
function insert_after_shortcode( $content ) {
    if( ! has_shortcode( $content, 'shortcode_name' ) ) {
        return $content;
    }

    ob_start();
  ?>

    <div id="bannerHTML"><!-- banner HTML goes here --></div>

  <?php

    $additional_html = ob_get_clean();
    preg_match_all( '/'. get_shortcode_regex() .'/s', $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER );

    if( ! empty( $matches ) ) {

        foreach ( $matches as $shortcode ) {

            if ( 'shortcode_name' === $shortcode[2] ) {
                $new_content = $shortcode[0] . $additional_html;
                $content     = str_replace( $shortcode[0], $new_content, $content );
            }
        }
    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'insert_after_shortcode' );
```